# Do magnetic things fall faster?

Tags: gravity, magnetic-fields, earth

Assuming correct orientation, do magnetic things fall faster than non-magnetic ones because of the magnetic field of the Earth? Of course it is clear that if any, the effect is very very small, but there should be one, right? How would one calculate how small this impact is?

Comment: Are you interested only in the interaction between magnetic fields? Because an accelerating *conductor* in a magnetic field will have a changing equilibrium potential across it thanks to the Lorentz force $\vec F = q\vec v \times \vec B$, and moving charges around to set up that equilibrium potential takes energy which is stolen from the gravitationally-induced kinetic energy.

Answer (score 2):

Within a room size volume, the magnetic field of the earth is uniform.  A magnetic dipole only experiences a net translating force in a non-uniform magnetic field. (And that depends on its orientation.)

Answer (score 0):

To put [R.W. Bird’s answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/619565/279176) into layman terms, and expand on it slightly:

1. The Earth’s magnetic field can be safely treated as uniform within a region the size of a room.
2. A uniform magnetic field does not affect the way an object moves (it can only rotate an object), and therefore does not affect the way an object falls.